# PERL | Not getting the value after second submit

Tags: perl, cgi

everyone.

I'm doing an tool with Perl that actually verifies a status in the database and if necessary it gets the properly queries and after confirmation it updates the value.

The page has three possible contents:

If the query that will be used is already filled it updates and returns the status.

If only the serial that the user input is filled it generates the query and then asks for confirmation.

If none of those 2 variables are already filled it goes to the main form where the user can submit the serial.

The problem that I'm facing is that after it generates the `$final_query` and shows up for confirmation, when I click the Confirm button it reloads the page but it pass directly through the `if($final_query)` and even the `elseif` that verifies if the `$serial_no` is already set.

Does Perl really lose those values if I perform a second submit or am I doing something wrong?

I'd love to have some explanation about it because it's the second time that I'm doing something with that language.

Thanks in advance!

--edit

I chopped the code to show where it defines the $final_query but I kept the structure to help in the understanding.

The full code is available at http://pastebin.com/6NqhbVau

```
#headers
if ($final_query) {

        $content = "<h1>first if</h1>";
#updateESNDatabase($database, $final_query);

#it only enters here if the user type the ESN
}elsif ($serial_no) {
        #selects the database
            switch(checkUpdateNeeded($database, $serial_no)) {
                case 0 {
            #Shows that the updates are no needed
                }
                case 1 {
                    $final_query = `cat $query1`;
                    chop($final_query);
                    $final_query =~ s/SERIALNUM/$serial_no/g;
                    $final_query =~ s/LOGINID/$login_id/g;
                    $content = $cgi->start_form .
                    "<center>" .
                        "<h3> Please double check the queries below before you update on database </h3>" .
                    "</center>" . 
                    $cgi->submit("Confirm") . $cgi->end_form;

                    $content .= $final_query;

                }
                case 2 {
                    #Makes almost the same as the first case, it only uses a different file to generate the query.
                }
            }
} else {
    #Generates the first page, where the users inputs information
} 
$page->set_content($content);
$page->process;
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to narrow your question down a bit, describe exactly which code your problem concerns, and what you expect it to do instead.

Comment: @TLP Sure. I'll edit right now to make it clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `Switch` is a deprecated module. Don't use the other version `given/when` which is also .. not good. Use `if` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @TLP I'll modify that. :) Also, I edited the post. There is the code that fills the variable that looses its value after submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to perform this.
As per my analysis I cannot simply create a variable and pass it through the cgi form.

To workaround this what I've done is create a hidden input in HTML and then send the variable through it.

```
<input type='hidden' name='the_query' value=\"$final_query\">
```